# SignalR error using high level hub api with MVC4 - "/echo/negotiate 404 Not Found Error"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have some very basic SignalR code running on the js client:

```
var conn = $.connection("@Url.Content("/echo")");

conn.Debug = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

conn.start();
```

This code executes and works, except I get a 404 Error. The JS is trying to access http://localhost:32344/echo/negotiate and it can't find it. If I hit the url without the "negotiate", the request completes.

I did not touch the Global.asax, and the server code is as basic as it gets, but there are not calls to this code from the client yet:

```
public class SpatialHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string data)
    {
        Caller.Debug("sent!");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing the "High level hub" client side server code with the "low level connection" client side API.

Follow the quick starts here for and end to end example of each:

- [Connections](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections)
- [Hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server)

Answer (score 0):

I see where I went wrong. I was looking for a solution to a different problem and mixed up the two. However, I've learned that one must include method calls in hub.start if the method call is happening immediately:

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
     myhub.send('test');
});
```